# ReactJS - What's the difference between using useRef and putting a variable outside of the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ecmascript-6

What's the difference between this code:

```
function MyComponent(){
    const isPersistent = useRef(true)
    // some more code...
}
```

and this code:

```
let isPersistent = true
function MyComponent(){
    // some more code...
}
```

I know I would usually put useRef for these. I'd never actually do it the second way, I just wanna know why. what's the difference between these? I know I can useRef to also put on an HTML element. but if that's not the case, why isn't the second one good practice?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to track changes if you didn't use useRef

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be useful to track the DOM properties as well ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second way has a value that is applicable to ALL instances of `MyComponent`, whereas the first way has a value that can be unique per instance of `MyComponent`.

<s>In addition, changing `isPersistent` in the second case may not trigger re-renders.</s> [edit] The previous sentence was mistaken, thanks to KcH in the comments. `useRef` doesn't trigger renders either.

It should be noted that there may in fact be circumstances where you WOULD want to use the second pattern, having an `isPersistent` variable that's external to the class and is effectively "global" for all instances of that class.

Comment: great first point  ... also ref changes don't trigger re-render (I mean for the same reason we would use them )